# In ICA Client Object API for Citrix Receiver/Workspace, does setting OutputMode really work?

Tags: powershell, dll, sdk, activex, citrix

I follow the specification of [Citrix ICA Client Object API Specification](http://www.citrix.com/static/cdn/archivedsdks/icaobjectsdk/ICA_Client_Object_Guide_v10x.pdf)

According to this documentation, you can set OutputMode property which has the following meaning:

- OutputMode: Output mode for the client engine.

Valid values

- 0(non-headless),
- 1(normal),
- 2(renderless),
- 3(windowless)

So I set in my code the value to 3 which has the following meaning:

> OutputModeWindowless= 3
>   The client runs as normal, but does not display in the session window. Maintains
>   internal bitmap surface for screen snapshots. Select this mode to prevent the
>   client from drawing to the screen if client CPU usage is identified as a
>   bottleneck. Rendering still occurs in the background to an off-screen surface,
>   making it possible to obtain screen captures of the session if desired.

But there is absolutely no difference in behaviour, I still see the window as in Normal mode.

I have ensured I set it before connecting as per [this documentation](http://www.citrix.com/static/cdn/archivedsdks/simulsdk/9.x/sim_api_specification_programmers_guide.pdf):

> OutputMode must be defined only at load-time; that is, before a connection is
>   launched.

I have seen this issue is faced by other developers:

- https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/278410-outputmode-windowsless-and-renderless-help-on/
- https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/372758-ica-api-icaclientoutputmode-does-not-change-anything/#comment-1904176
- https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/372758-ica-api-icaclientoutputmode-does-not-change-anything/#comment-2001192
- https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/393456-starting-a-ica-session-in-mode-outputmodewindowless/#comment-2001191
- https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/278410-outputmode-windowsless-and-renderless-help-on/#comment-1515471

So question:

- Is this method really implemented ?
- If yes, what needs to be done to make it work ?

Here is sample code I used:

```
[system.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("c:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Citrix\ICA Client\WfIcaLib.dll")
$icaClient = New-Object WFICALib.ICAClientClass
$icaClient.CacheICAFile = $false
$icaClient.ICAFile = $icapath
$icaClient.OutputMode = [WfIcaLib.OutputMode]::OutputModeWindowless
$icaClient.Launch = $true
$icaClient.TWIMode = $true
$icaClient.Connect()

sleep 10

$enumHandle = $icaClient.EnumerateCCMSessions()
$sessionid = $icaClient.GetEnumNameByIndex($enumHandle, 0)
$icaClient.StartMonitoringCCMSession($sessionid, $true)
#$icaClient.session.ReplayMode = $true

$icaClient.session.Keyboard.SendKeyDown(16) # shift key
$icaClient.session.Keyboard.SendKeyDown(53) # number 5 key

$screenShot = $icaClient.session.CreateFullScreenShot()
$screenShot.Save()
$icaClient.Logoff()

sleep 10

$icaClient.StopMonitoringCCMSession($sessionid)
$icaClient.CloseEnumHandle($enumHandle)
```

I am using:

- Citrix Receiver/Workspace versions I tried: 4.12, 4.9, Workspace 19.11
- Citrix StoreFront version: 3.12.5000